# why is try-catch not allowing other elements in java applet to appear?

Tags: java, applet, try-catch

I am populating my java applet. I am trying to get serverSocket to work with my java applet. Once I add in the try-catch, all the other elements in the applet does not show up in the applet. When I comment out the try-catch block, the other elements come back. Why does this happen?
Here is the code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class App extends Applet {

TextField input;
TextField output;

public void init()
{

    setSize(500,500);

}

public void start ()
{

    this.input = new TextField(40);
    this.output = new TextField(40);
    this.output.setEditable(false);
    Button b = new Button("send");

    this.add(b);
    this.add(input);
    this.add(output);

  try{

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8000);
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        DataInputStream inputFromClient = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        final DataOutputStream outputToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());

        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {



            }


        });



  }catch(IOException e){

      e.printStackTrace();

  } 


}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Socket socket = server.accept();` is a blocking method, meaning that until some connection is made, it will wait, so `start` will never return, so the UI won't be updated

Off load the socket connection code to a separate thread.

Beware, that it might not be possible to establish this kind of connection from within a applet, based on the security settings of the local machine.

Also, AWT was superseded by Swing some 15+ years ago, you might find it easier to use either the Swing API or JavaFX as there is more community based support

Comment: To the MadProgrammer: Thank you for your help. I'm going to edit my code.